# remove a element from a StackPanel and add it to other StackPanel

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

is it possible to remove a item e.g. a `TextBlock` from a `StackPanel` and add it to a other `StackPanel`?

My XAML Code looks like this:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="PanelStack1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,86">
    <Rectangle x:Name="RecX" />
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel x:Name="PanelStack2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,86" />
```

I want to move the `RecX` from the `PanelStack1` to `PanelStack2` via my C# Code. Is this possible?

This is just a small example, in my real code there are many elements which have to been moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your code behind:

```
 PanelStack1.Children.Remove(RecX);
 PanelStack2.Children.Add(RecX);
```

Comment: if you do this code behind procedures, your app will crash in a certain case : if you grab your app from the top (like for example trying to enter Filled/Snapped Mode) and let it go (just grab and let it go, to go again in fullscreen again), it will crash and tell you that RecX already exists in the Visual Tree and can't be added again. A workaround can be like this : if (!PanelStack2.Children.Contains(RecX)) PanelStack2.Children.Add(RecX);